# Hide HTML Form Before the page loads using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, hide, display

I would like to hide a HTML Form before even the page loads using javascript.

I was able to use **display='none'** style property to hide the form using javascript but the form content loads visible for a second before disappearing.

```
var searchbar = document.getElementById("searchform");
searchbar.style.display = 'none';
```

I have read many solutions in stackoverflow adding some css code in the page and display the content later using **removeClass**.

Problem is **I do not have access to code behind the web page to add the CSS content**. However **I can add some custom javascript code only in header or a footer.(cannot use jQuery as well).**

Please let me know if its possible hiding the form element as expected.
I am quite new to javascripting. Please provide your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Maybe you can load the form in a hidden element like a div? With javascript there is no way to make something before the page loads.

Comment: why not use css

Comment: as mentioned I cannot add css code. I dont have access to add it.

Comment: Can you show us the html JavaScript -so we can see the transient effect?

Comment: Can you add css to your own page?

Comment: When exactly does your form hide? At the exact moment the page is fully loaded or a few seconds after that?

Comment: hes probably trying to temper with someone elses page, since he does not have the code...

Comment: Unfortunately, Its not our own-page. We configure the web pages using the some tools(Something like WordPress) for the customer. Using the tool we cannot customize everything in web page. But we can customize somethings in web page by adding some custom javascript code in header and footer using the tool. Hence we dont have access to any HTML, CSS or JS of the webpage (its generated by the tools itself).

Comment: Corrected my question a bit. May be you guys got my question wrongly. hopefully this helps

Comment: That is impossible to hide from javascript at once before page loaded ! Your html and css are loaded faster than javascript so form will display first but after page loaded your script will hide form !

Comment: Thank you for your answer David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: Sorry, if you only can use some javascript and cannot access the html or css there is probably no solution for your problem.

Comment: exactly what you said, "Just read the full question before you answer it."

Comment: I dont have access to HTML CSS or JS code of the page. And cannot do anything with Jquery as mentioned. Only option is to add some Custom js script in header or footer of the page.

Comment: Well @Stormhashe i thougt he wants to integrate a form from an external page onto a page where he has access to the code. My bad. :)

Comment: thanks you Vampyr for your answer. I was just checking if that was possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all you form in a javascript variable, and write it in your div when the page is ready

Simple example :

```
function showForm(){
    var container = $('#formContainer');
    var form = '<input type="text" name="myInput">'; // Or you can load it from an external file
    container.html(form);
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    showForm();

});
```

But the best way is adding a css rule to hide your form, and show it when the page is loaded.

Comment: He can only use plain javascript.

Comment: I dont have access to HTML CSS or JS code of the page. And cannot do anything with Jquery as mentioned. Only option is to add some Custom js script in header or footer of the page.

Answer (score -1):

Web browser first render HTML. It takes time, while browser download css or js file. Best apprach would be to use inline display='none', not in css file.

```
<form style="display:none;">
   ...
</form>
```